# Implications of changing address of my credit card temporarily?

Tags: taxes, credit-card, new-york

A gym that I attend requires a yearly contract with the option of breaking it if moving out of the state.

A change address of a credit card can be accepted as a proof. Is it possible to change the address temporarily to somewhere outside my state (NY) and then change it back again? Are there any tax implications?

Comment: I believe this would be called "fraud".

Comment: If you change your credit card's address, the new address will probably be permanently linked to your credit history, too.  So I doubt there's tax implications, but there's certainly credit ones.  (Even aside from the fraud aspect)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking about the possibility of committing fraud.

Comment: Does the contract say you have to change your _domicile_ to another state?  If the contract terms are as limited as "a change of CC address is an allowed reason to terminate the contract" then, while that may or may not be the gym's intent, there is no fraud if OP changes their credit card address.  NY has a large population of "snowbirds" who tend to change their credit card addresses twice per year; are there any known examples at this gym of such a member who goes to Florida for the winter?  Do you know what happens with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purposes of this answer lets ignore any accusation of fraud.

The first thing that occurs to me is that the first change of address should cause the credit card company to send a written notice your old address. That notice is designed to alert the people at the address that somebody submitted a change of address. Of course after you have convinced the gym that you have moved, when you change the address back to the first address, they will send a notice to 2nd address.  If that address exists the people there may wonder what is going on. So you might want to tell them.

If that credit card is offered by your bank, then the address changes might cause them to wonder if the mailing address associated with the bank account should also change.

The credit card company shouldn't send you a new card, but make sure it isn't near the time the current card expires, or it might get sent to the wrong address.

During the period that the card is associated with the out of state address, remember to punch in the new zip code when pumping gas, because the card readers at the pump always want to know the mailing address associated with the card. It is possible that other vendor systems will ask this question.

Longer term there is always a chance that the new address will become associated with your credit file. Sometimes your are asked questions regarding old mailing addresses as a proof if identification. Remember that that street, or town might be mentioned during an identity check years from now.

It shouldn't cause a tax issue. But it could. If the tax authority is looking for people that are skipping paying for things such as car taxes, and income tax, they could be getting data about people who are moving in. It could look to them liked you moved.

There is also a slight chance there could be a voting issue. If somebody is looking for people who have a  voting address not matching their mailing address. I don't know which databases they use for reference.